# How to determine which variables need to be trimmed in PCA or Factor analysis?

Tags: spss, pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

**Background:** I'm working with log returns for about 400 tech stocks. I want to use PCA to reduce these into principal components (Internet companies, software developers, circuit board manufacturers, etc), which then are to be used as sector-related indices. Parallel analysis is my method of determining how many factors to extract in the first place. Rotation is done via Oblimin with Kaiser Normalization in SPSS.

**Questions:** How do I determine which variables need to be trimmed? Those with low communality? Or should I look at the pattern matrix and start cutting variables which happen to load on multiple factors? After that, can I use the figures in the pattern matrix to weight each stock's contribution to each component's variance? For example, if the rotation yields .71 for Stock A and .10 for Stock B, I could multiply the return for each stock in each period, T, by its respective weight.

Comment: Why communality bothers you? Is that because your aim is to do factor analysis and not PCA?

Comment: I think that factor analysis, in particular CFA, is a better approach in this case than PCA. It seems to me that the OP wants to reduce dimensionality by considering latent variables.

Comment: Why do you want to "trim" any variables at all?